# Slide-In Nav Overlay

Tags: jquery, css, navigation

I have a template for an `off-screen nav` that slides in from the left when a `toggle` is clicked.  What I'd like to happen is when the `nav` slides in, an overlay darkens the content behind it.  To do this, I wrapped the page content in a `div` and tried to add a BG color to cover the content, but it doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone help? Code Below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var toggle = $('.toggle');
 var osNav = $('.offScreen-nav');
 var pageContainer = $('.page-container');
 
 toggle.click(function() {
  osNav.toggleClass('showNav');
  pageContainer.toggleClass('navOnScreen')
 });
})
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

nav {
 width: 100%;
 height: 70px;
 //border: 1px solid;
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: flex-end;
}

.toggle {
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 border: 1px solid;
 background-color: rgba(17,17,17, .9);
 opacity: .9;
 margin: 20px 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
 align-self: center;
}

main {
 height: 1000px;
 background-color: #ddd;
}

.offScreen-nav {
 width: 340px;
 height: 100vh;
 position: fixed;
 margin-left: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 z-index: 2000;
 background-color: rgba(17,17,17, .9);
 transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
 transform: translate3d(-340px,0,0);
}

.showNav {
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.page-container {
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
 transition-delay: .1s;
}

.page-container.navOnScreen {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .6);
 transform: translate3d(20px,0,0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="offScreen-nav"></div>

<div class="page-container">
 <nav>
 <div class="toggle"></div>
</nav>
 <main></main> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I normally do is add another element called overlay and toggle it as you are toggling the nav item to produce that effect. I would also move the toggle button out of the nav so as you can give it a position absolute as you will need to apply a z-index to keep it visible when the overlay is enabled. See below... Hope it helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var toggle = $('.toggle');
 var osNav = $('.offScreen-nav');
 var overlay = $('.overlay');
 var pageContainer = $('.page-container');
 
 toggle.click(function() {
  osNav.toggleClass('showNav');
  overlay.toggleClass('showNav');
  pageContainer.toggleClass('navOnScreen')
 });
})
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

nav {
 width: 100%;
 height: 70px;
 //border: 1px solid;
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: flex-end;
}

.toggle {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid;
    background-color: rgba(17,17,17, .9);
    opacity: .9;
    /* margin: 20px 15px; */
    cursor: pointer;
    align-self: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 15px;
    z-index: 2;
}

main {
 height: 1000px;
 background-color: #ddd;
}

.offScreen-nav {
 width: 340px;
 height: 100vh;
 position: fixed;
 margin-left: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 z-index: 2000;
 background-color: rgba(17,17,17, .9);
 transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
 transform: translate3d(-340px,0,0);
}

.showNav {
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.page-container {
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
 transition-delay: .1s;
}

.page-container.navOnScreen {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .6);
 transform: translate3d(20px,0,0);
}
.overlay.showNav {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: blue;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
}
.overlay{
 transition:0.3s ease; 
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="offScreen-nav"></div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="toggle"></div>

<div class="page-container">
 <nav>
</nav>
 <main></main> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `background-color` from `nav` & `main` as well (it is currently overlapping the `body`'s background color) like,

**In JS:**

```
// Toggle a class which removes background-color from main & nav
nav.toggleClass('remove-bg')
main.toggleClass('remove-bg')
```

**In CSS:**

```
/* Resetting background-color to transparent */
.remove-bg {
  background: transparent;
}

/* To get the transition well */
main, nav {
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: .1s;
}
```

**Have a look at the snippet below:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var toggle = $('.toggle');
 var osNav = $('.offScreen-nav');
 var pageContainer = $('.page-container');
 var nav = $('nav');
  var main = $('main');
 
 toggle.click(function() {
  osNav.toggleClass('showNav');
  pageContainer.toggleClass('navOnScreen')
    nav.toggleClass('remove-bg')
    main.toggleClass('remove-bg')
 });
})
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

nav {
 width: 100%;
 height: 70px;
 //border: 1px solid;
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: flex-end;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
 transition-delay: .1s;
}

.toggle {
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 border: 1px solid;
 background-color: rgba(17,17,17, .9);
 opacity: .9;
 margin: 20px 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
 align-self: center;
}

main {
 height: 1000px;
 background-color: #ddd;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
 transition-delay: .1s;
}

.offScreen-nav {
 width: 340px;
 height: 100vh;
 position: fixed;
 margin-left: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 z-index: 2000;
 background-color: rgba(17,17,17, .9);
 transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
 transform: translate3d(-340px,0,0);
}

.showNav {
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.page-container {
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
 transition-delay: .1s;
}

.page-container.navOnScreen {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .6);
 transform: translate3d(20px,0,0);
}

.remove-bg {
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="offScreen-nav"></div>

<div class="page-container">
 <nav>
 <div class="toggle"></div>
</nav>
 <main></main> 
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var toggle = $('.toggle');
  var osNav = $('.offScreen-nav');
  var pageContainer = $('.page-container');
  var darkLayer = $('main, nav');

  toggle.click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('border');
    osNav.toggleClass('showNav');
    darkLayer.toggleClass('darkLayer');
    pageContainer.toggleClass('navOnScreen');
  });
})
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

nav {
 width: 100%;
 height: 70px;
 //border: 1px solid;
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: flex-end;
}

.toggle {
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 border: 1px solid;
 background-color: rgba(17,17,17, .9);
 opacity: .9;
 margin: 20px 15px;
 cursor: pointer;
 align-self: center;
}

main {
 height: 1000px;
 background-color: #ddd;
}

.offScreen-nav {
 width: 340px;
 height: 100vh;
 position: fixed;
 margin-left: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 z-index: 2000;
 background-color: rgba(17,17,17, .9);
 transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
 transform: translate3d(-340px,0,0);
}

.showNav {
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.page-container {
 transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
 transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
 transition-delay: .1s;
}

.page-container.navOnScreen {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
 transform: translate3d(20px,0,0);
}

.darkLayer {
  background: #333;
  opacity: .5;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}

.border {
  border-color: #fff;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="offScreen-nav"></div>

<div class="page-container">
  <nav>
    <div class="toggle"></div>
  </nav>
  <main></main> 
</div>
```